# What effect, if any, does "choosing" an enemy strategy have?

Tags: endless-space-2

In the advanced battle options, you can choose from 3 different strategies the **enemy** might take (shown below).

[image: ES2 enemy battle options]

Is this available purely to view the effects of what those strategies would have *if* the enemy chose them, or does guessing which strategy the enemy will choose give some sort of benefit?

Comment: Looks like this has been refactored quite a bit as this isn't really a thing in-game anymore. Now, you simply see what the enemy has most commonly used against you, which in my experience, tends to be the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from what I have observed in singleplayer games.

If you click on an enemy tactic then you can compare if their tactic is better with their composition and use a corresponding counter-tactic to gain an upper hand.

You are in effectively simulating what would happen if the enemy picked THIS particular tactic and can plan around it.

IE If you see close vs close and you will have high loses. So you change to another tactic that has less chance of a bad match up.

There should be a % compatibility number below each side's tactic box try to aim for highest average. IE if all of your ship have nothing but close-range weapon you might want to pick close. Eventually start mixing it up if AI is getting better compatibility than you are.

Answer (score 0):

**None**

This lets you better see how your opponents' options would affect you. It's kind of like if this was a game of  Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock, you could select Spock (for example) and see which option(s) you pick would have which affect on the outcome of the battle. Additionally if your opponent is predictable (say they always choose sniper) you could better pick the best counter to their likely choice. However selecting these doesn't actually affect what the opponent will choose (unless they're looking over your shoulder while you're clicking through them, and then it's all mindgames).